# How to show a div depends on what user choose from select option form with js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to show a different div depends on what user choose from the main html php select option form. Here is the form:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
                      <select name="pages">
                        <option value="home">home page</option>
                        <option value="blogs">blogs page</option>
                        <option value="aboutus">aboutus page</option>
                      </select></br>
                    </form>

    <div>
...
    </div>
```

For example if a user clicked on **"home"** the page will redirect automatically (without refreshing) and show a div of homepage under the form & if user clicked on **"blogs"** , the home div will be disappeared and the div of blogs will be appeared! I have no idea on how to do this with js but please if you know how ,give me some tips. thanks!

Comment: there are a lot of different implementations for this. i'd recommend using a javascript framework such as angular.

Comment: "redirect" can not be without refreshing. If you want to implement it without refreshing i'd advice you to discover XMLHttpRequest. However this is not crossbrowser, so you can just use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Under select you can create `<div class="content"></div>` and load a content to there. However it requires some work on server. It seems like you do not have enough knowledge to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using jquery:

```
$('#select-pages').on('change', function() {
    $('#my-div').html(this.value);
```

})

https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/6g1hj42e/